# Fingerprint sensor with external memory source

Tags: arduino-uno

I am building a door lock that we will use at a local MakerSpace-club in my city, and we had this idea about building a fingerprint lock with parts compatible with Arduino.

What we are aiming to do is create a database that holds all our customers and their associated information. Fingerprint data being one of them.

So my question is: Is it possible to have a fingerprint sensor **store and compare fingerprint data** with an **external source** such as a **MySQL database**, instead of using the on-board memory?

So basically: When a customer puts his finger on the sensor, the Arduino board grabs the fingerprint data and queries our database for a match through its WiFi shield. If match is found: Log entry and unlock the door.

*Google is not helping me out here.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you need is a computer or another device that grabs the data via wifi and store it in a database.

You can simply send requests from arduino to computer and the PC does the search and returns the info back.

If you use XBees for communication, just install some serial communication with your preferred language and start sending and receiving data. The database will be accessed through that high level program and data will flow via XBees.